# How to embed WebKit into my C/C++/Win32 application?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, webkit, embedding

The solutions I have found are irrelevant:

- someone used WebKit in a Delphi project
- someone used it with Java
- there is QtWebKit (about:blank demo app takes 44 megs)
- .Net port of it
- GTK+ port

I need a guide how to embed WebKit instance into a pure C/C++ application under Win32.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Brent Fulgham has put lots of work into producing a Windows Cairo port of WebKit, which doesn't rely on Apple's proprietary backend stuff (e.g. CoreGraphics, CoreFoundation, CFNetwork). I believe that is what you are after. The details aren't entirely collated in one place, but there is [some information in the Trac wiki](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/BuildingCairoOnWindows) and other bits are dotted around on [Brent's blog](http://whtconstruct.blogspot.com/search/label/webkit).

**EDIT**: [Link to Brent's project on sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencflite/)

**EDIT 2**: [News of some interesting progress from Brent's blog](http://whtconstruct.blogspot.com/2011/04/towards-simpler-wincairo-build.html)

Comment: I would notice also, this way although acceptable requires some significant effort from developer (unlike Qt widget embedding) and is not a from-A-to-Z embedding guide. It would be nice if there is an easier solution.

Comment: Easier solutions, by default, do not exist.  Someone must make them.

Comment: Still no easier way than this??

Answer (score 3):

WebKit for Windows are still use VS 2005.
So, if you use VS2010 or 2012, you need to build WebKit on this VS from source, because different vc*.dll runtime redistributable versions.

For example, you can use [Brent Fulgham's test project](https://github.com/bfulgham/CallJS) and advices to build WebKit on new VS [from this blog](http://blog.ashodnakashian.com/tag/webkit/) to test your build.

Answer (score 2):

Embed WebKit In 3D Games

https://sourceforge.net/projects/wke/