# Gecko XPCOM usage vs WebKit

Tags: c++, delphi, webkit, gecko

I need to embed a web browser in C++ application. As well, I need to reach its javascript methods from Delphi components.

I know that for FF there is Gecko with XPCOM. Is there something like this for WebKit?

Comment: Post like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924255/how-to-embed-webkit-into-my-c-c-win32-application

Comment: @floatless: It's a different question. I need to know if it allows to inovke Javascript methods!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WebKit first: there's project called Chromium embedded (Chromium is basically WebKit rendering engine and V8 Javascript engine), that has also [Delphi support](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/). After a quick look into headers, I did not find a way to access JS methods, but it allows executing javascript snippets in given frame:

```
// Execute a string of JavaScript code in this frame. The |script_url|
// parameter is the URL where the script in question can be found, if any. The
// renderer may request this URL to show the developer the source of the
// error.  The |start_line| parameter is the base line number to use for error
// reporting.
execute_java_script: procedure(self: PCefFrame; const jsCode, scriptUrl: PWideChar; startLine: Integer); stdcall;
```

So the pieces are there, you just need to figure out how to patch them together.

For Gecko, there are Delphi bindings available under a project called [d-gecko](http://sourceforge.net/projects/d-gecko/). But it seems to be a bit outdated and also does not seem to allow accessing the Javascript.

Comment: Good to know that the 'delphi chromium embedded' project!

Answer (score 2):

You may take a look at [this project](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/) which allows you to embed the chromium web browser in Delphi applications.