# Two window Web App

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

I want to create a Web App (HTML5 and JS) where the user sees **two pages** in the **same window.**

The Problem is that I can't put one page in an iFrame because it is an external site with restrictions.

Kinda sth like Dual Screen Browser without the browser's adress line would be my goal. Is this possible? Any programs to do this?

If yes, they should interact with each other. I think WebSocket is here what I need. Can I do this session-based? So every user-action is unique?

I'm very new to this, sorry if it is a dumb question.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Different answers for different operating systems, but there are [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/) in the Apple ecosphere and on Windows there is ieframe.dll, which is old and of course limited to Internet Explorer.

There is also [a post on embedding Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311435/how-do-i-embed-webkit-in-a-window) which may be relevant, though it is five years old.