# Embedding WebKit in a Windows application: Licensing issues?

Tags: c++, windows, webkit

I have a questions with regards to using Webkit as a component in a Windows application. I know there are options for embedding a browser, but they are overkill for my needs.

Looking at the [WebKit licensing page](https://webkit.org/licensing-webkit/), it seems that the licenses are permissible; the traditional BSD license and the Library GPL license, the latter of which allows me to distribute my application as "work that uses the library". This is also stated [here](https://webkit.org/project/). However, I've found several posts (including on Stackoverflow, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11167123/6365537)) that say that Apple has some proprietary code in there which doesn't allow its redistribution. Is this an inconsistency, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

There are two WebKit Windows ports at the moment:

- AppleWin port
- WinCairo port

WebKit itself is licensed under LGPL and BSDL.
But, AppleWin port uses Apple's proprietary WebKit Support Library.
This can't be redistributed.
https://developer.apple.com/opensource/internet/webkit_sptlib_agree.html