# Embedding WebKit in C++ Application

Tags: html, c++, user-interface, webkit, sdl

I'm writing a game in C++ using the SDL framework, and want to create my game's GUI using HTML/CSS. I've looked into frameworks such as [Awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com), however I'm turned off by the fact that it's not open source. I want to create my own implementation of a similar idea.

However, I can find almost no documentation on actually using WebKit in this manner. The closest I can find is this [Apple Developer guide to using WebKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/DisplayWebContent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000164-SW1) but it's targeted at MacOS-specific applications written in Objective-C. It makes mention of a "Webkit C Reference" toward the bottom of the page, but I cannot find this actual document anywhere. Additionally, I've read the resources on the [WebKit Wiki](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki) as well as [prior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924255/how-to-embed-webkit-into-my-c-c-win32-application) [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311435/how-do-i-embed-webkit-in-a-window) questions on the same topic, but I haven't been able to find anything in the way of direct, clear documentation on embedding WebKit in a C++ program.

Does this documentation exist somewhere? What is the best resource for documentation on embedding WebKit within a C++ application?

Comment: got how to embed webkit/blink in c++ yet? i want it too

Answer (score -3):

I'm not really sure about this, but when I read about "c++" and "html/css". QT comes to my mind. Maybe you want to check it out.