# Smallest/most compact embedded WebKit/Chrome HTML control for C# apps?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, webkit, controls

In other words -- **What is the smallest, most compact (fewest DLL, preferably single-DLL), cache-less, local-only, lightest weight, Chrome/WebKit/Blink-based embeddable HTML control for C#?**

My project requires a WebKit/Chromium/Blink compatible engine in an embedded window (local resources only, no Internet access, no cache folder, thumbdrive friendly, offline computer friendly, kiosk friendly, no automatic update notifications, downloads disabled).

A huge deal of embeddable HTML controls already exist, such as CefSharp (Chromium Embedded Framework CEF), Awesomium, Chrome Frame, WebKit .NET Wrapper, etc.  I have tried to install a few, and they work, but I need a framework intentionally designed for compactness.

Which ones support single-library-file (DLL) operation with minimal modification?  Even statically link into a single executable file?  Most of them install a huge mess of DLL and supplementary files and subfolders (cache, etc) and are WAY too heavyweight for my specific needs.

I have an existing designed-for-offline web project (fully Chrome tested and trusted) that I need to miniaturize into a compact, few-files offline readonly installation.  Initially, I have spent time (days) de-clutter a heavyweight CefSharp installation which refuses to statically link, and I can continue doing so.  However, I'd appreciate collective insight on lightweight embedded WebKit/Chromium/Blink options.  This is for Windows now, but I need to keep the door open to porting to Linux/Mac (Mono C#) so that's why I'm avoiding OS-specific engines (Safari/IE).

**Indirect Related StackOverflow Questions**

*Indirectly related on existence (but unfortunately not on question of "lightest weight) ...*

- [Is there an embeddable Webkit component for Windows / C# development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142184/is-there-an-embeddable-webkit-component-for-windows-c-sharp-development)
- [Use Chrome engine in WebBrowser control WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983787/use-chrome-engine-in-webbrowser-control-winforms)
- [Options for embedding Chromium instead of IE WebBrowser control with WPF/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119125/options-for-embedding-chromium-instead-of-ie-webbrowser-control-with-wpf-c)
- [Embedding WebKit in C++ Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43465126/embedding-webkit-in-c-application)

Comment: Just a heads up, there's a costly (almost-$1000) single-DLL option called EO.WebBrowser, but that is Windows only and also costly for an open source project.